# Set web-mode engine per directory

Tags: syntax-highlighting, web-mode

I'm hoping this is possible. I work in a variety of environments and languages. Right now it's mostly django and Node.js, but there have been others. What I would like to do is set the `web-mode` engine based on the project I am currently working on, and not the file extension. I know I could use `.djhtml` as the file extension, but that messes things up for others who aren't using Emacs because, for example, Pycharm doesn't know what to do with a `.djhtml` file. I would prefer to keep my `.html` if at all possible.

I am wondering if there is any way to set the `web-mode` engine based on the project I'm working in. I'd rather not have to put `-*- engine: django -*-` into each of my files either, if I can avoid it.

**UPDATE**:

I've tried adding the following to a `.dir-locals.el` file, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I get prompted to allow the variable change, and the value of the variable `web-mode-engines-alist` has changed to `(("django" . "\\.html\\'"))`, but `django` is not set as the template engine when I open a `.html` file.

```el
((web-mode .
    ((web-mode-engines-alist .
          (("django" . "\\.html\\'"))))))
```

**UPDATE 2**

To clarify, I can set all `.html` files to open with the django engine by putting the following in my `.spacemacs` file:

```el
(setq web-mode-engines-alist
      '(("django" . "\\.html\\'")))
```

That works just fine, but sets it globally, meaning I'll get the django engine in any `.html` file, regardless if it's a django project or another language.

**SYSTEM INFORMATION**

- Emacs: 25.2.1
- OS: Windows 10

I found this bug reported in `web-mode` (https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/issues/799), but it's just referred to be asked as a question here.

Comment: Directory local variables might be the solution for you:
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html

Comment: I don't know why it's not working. But to get rid of the prompting for the variable change you need to update `safe-local-variable-values`.

Comment: I get the prompt to allow `safe-local-variable-values` when I load it up. That doesn't fix the problem, though.

Comment: Do you know that the regexps associated with auto-mode-alist work on the (full) path not just the filename ? If you want a setting by project, it might be the solution. There is an example on http://web-mode.org

Comment: @fxbois I don't want to have to each of my projects to my `init.el`. It seems like `dir-locals.el` would be the way to do this, but for some reason `web-mode` isn't recognizing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding a web-mode-hook to check if you are in a projectile project? You would also have to check if the projectile project is a django one, but I am not that familiar with django.

```el
(defun cesco/django ()
    (if (projectile-project-p)
        (if (file-exists-p (concat (projectile-project-root) "manage.py"))
            (web-mode-set-engine "django")
            (message "do not exists") ;; You can safely delet this line
            )
        )
    )
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook 'cesco/django)
```

Comment: Though I, too, recommend `use-package`, it might be helpful for non-users to suggest the vanilla equivalent of this: `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html\\'" . django-mode))`

Comment: I don't want to use the `django-mode`. I just want to use `web-mode`'s django engine.

Comment: @Ryan I am just guessing here. I dont do django and use web-mode to typescript dev only

Comment: I also _only_ want to use the django engine for `.html` files if I'm working on a Django project. From the looks of it, this will switch it for all `.html` files. I tried using this snippet in the `dir-locals.el` file for the project, but that didn't work.

Comment: Passing an unquoted alist to `progn` is malformed lisp - the interpreter will try to call the first `car` (in this case `web-mode`) as a function, which I doubt is desirable. Passing a quoted alist to `progn` is a no-op. The alist should probably be assigned to some variable or passed to some function.

Comment: @Ryan updated answer

Comment: To check if it's a Django project, you could look in the root directory for `manage.py`.

Comment: @Ryan I think this might work. But I am still worried about it working just on the first attempt since it wont take django of the web-mode-engines-alist when you happen to open a regular html file later on. There should be a way to set the web-mode-engine just for the current buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution thanks to this recipe: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LocalVariables .

I set a custom variable in `.dir-locals`:

```lisp
((nil . ((mik-web-mode-engine . "django")))
 (python-mode (pyvenv-activate . "../pyenv/api_bo"))
 (mhtml-mode . ((mik-web-mode-engine . "django")
                (mode . web))))
```

Then I read it from a hook defined in my [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html):

```lisp
;; web-mode
(defun my-web-mode-hook ()
  "Hooks for Web mode. Add a local hook which set the engine to the one specified by
   `mik-web-mode-engine` local variable."
  (add-hook
   'hack-local-variables-hook
   (lambda ()
     (if (boundp 'mik-web-mode-engine)
         (progn
           (message "web-mode-engine is %s" mik-web-mode-engine)
           (web-mode-set-engine mik-web-mode-engine))
       (progn
         (message "no web-mode-engine settled")
         (web-mode-set-engine "none"))))))
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook  'my-web-mode-hook nil nil)
```

Note that I switch from `mhtml-mode` (the default on my setup) to `web-mode`. If you have defined `web-mode` as the default for HTML you don't need that.